# How to get type=USER_TTY record in audit.log?

Tags: linux, tty, linux-audit

What audit rule needs to be added to get `USER_TTY` record logged?

Whether it will record all the executed commands under `msg` field?

Answer (score 0):

Enable [pam_tty_audit](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_tty_audit), by placing this line in your /etc/pam.d/ files:

```
session required pam_tty_audit.so disable=bounce enable=root
```